# Having some trouble loading highcharts using backbone and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, highcharts, coffeescript

I've got a couple of files I'm working with trying to load a highchart. I suspect an issue with timing, but I can't pin point what the issue is. The chart appears to load sometimes but not others, and I am getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'highcharts'` any ideas?

This is my backbone view:

```
namespace "happiness_kpi", (exports) ->
  exports.chartView = Backbone.View.extend

    template: HandlebarsTemplates['templates/chart']

    el: '#lineChart'

    initialize: ->
      $.getScript "http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js", success: @buildChart()

    render: ->
      @$el.html HandlebarsTemplates.chart()

    buildChart: ->
      $.getScript "build_chart.coffee", success: @render()
```

and here is my js file that builds the chart:

```
$ ->
  $.getJSON "http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-  c.json&callback=?", (data) ->

    # Create the chart
    $('#lineChart').highcharts "StockChart",
      rangeSelector:
        selected: 1

      title:
        text: "Just Checking"

      series: [
        name: "Oakland University"
        data: data
        tooltip:
          valueDecimals: 2
      ]
```

I originally had the scripts being loaded in a hamlbars template, but I tried going about it a different way. I've had no luck either way I tried.

Comment: I just fixed the indentation. They now mirror my files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your problem or not but this:

```
$.getScript ..., success: @buildChart()
```

doesn't do what you think it does. That will call `@buildChart` when the argument list for `$.getScript` is being built and `$.getScript` will see whatever `@buildChart` returns as the `success` option's value. Similarly for the `$.getScript` call in `buildChart`.

Furthermore, `$.getScript` doesn't get its success callback from an options object the way `$.ajax` does, [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) just wants the second argument to be the function:

> **jQuery.getScript( url [, success(script, textStatus, jqXHR) ] )**
>
> **Description:** Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.

You probably want to say this:

```
initialize: ->
  $.getScript "http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js", @buildChart

render: =>
  @$el.html HandlebarsTemplates.chart()

buildChart: =>
  $.getScript "build_chart.coffee", @render
```

No parentheses on the functions that are `success` option values, you want to pass the functions, not call them. I've also switched `render` and `buildChart` to bound functions using [`=>`](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) so that they get the correct `this` when `$.getScript` calls them.

Comment: That is closer, but still doesn't appear to be working. It seems that the parens are necessary in order to call the other functions. I have console logged the functions, and I can see the order they're being called, but I'm still getting the same error. I wonder now, too, if they getScript in the buildChart function is the correct way to go about it. As of right now, when I test the code, it's performing a `GET`, and I don't think that is necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `$.getScript` argument convention, check my update please.

Comment: Ok, So I was able to get the charts rendered on the page. What I ended up doing was moving the build_chart code into my view. Once I did that, the chart would render sporadically. I then realized that the issue was that the Highcharts library was not loading quickly enough, before the page would render. I am now working on moving the Highcharts library local to the app, and I think that should fix the issue altogether.